# Meaning of () => Operator in C#, if it exists

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, operators

I read this interesting line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626931/method-call-overhead), in an answer by Jon Skeet.

The interesting line is this, where he advocated using a delegate:

```
Log.Info("I did something: {0}", () => action.GenerateDescription());
```

Question is, what is this ()=> operator, I wonder? I tried Googling it but since it's made of symbols Google couldn't be of much help, really. Did I embarrassingly miss something here?

Comment: Note that grammatically it is the => that is the operator and the () and the expression which are its operands. It's a strange operator; most binary operators take two expressions, not an argument list and an expression-or-block.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This introduces a lambda function (anonymous delegate) with no parameters, it's equivalent to and basically short-hand for:

```
delegate void () { return action.GenerateDescription(); }
```

You can also add parameters, so:

```
(a, b) => a + b
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
delegate int (int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

Comment: Roughly, indeed. For my series on some of the subtle differences between the lambda syntax and the anonymous method syntax start here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 10):

`=>` this is lambda operator. When we don't have any input parameters we just use round brackets `()` before lambda operator.

syntax: 
`(input parameters) => expression`

Answer (score 3):

Creating an anonymous delegate to specified method.

Probably, in your case it will be a `Func<string>`

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a lambda expression you can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+lambda).

Comment: Even better than sifting through SO is to go straight to the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Thank you. How about  
`public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>{webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();});` ? I don't understand `webBuilder =>{webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();});`

Answer (score 3):

It's way to pass anonymous delegate without parameters as lambda expression.

Similar to this from .NET 2.0

```
Log.Info("I did something: {0}", delegate()
            {
                return action.GenerateDescription();
            });
```

Comment: Probably `return action.GenerateDescription();`, no? Otherwise error "Can't cast void to string", something like that

Comment: @abatishchev, probably yes. Wrote it from top of my head, so I'm not sure it even compiles.

Comment: Could you please try and if it will fail - edit your post please?)